# How can I run a script which uses nuget package using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to use Roslyn to run code dynamically.

### Problem

When I want to run a code that uses NuGet packages through Roslyn, it fails because type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace.
How can I add the reference?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var option = ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports("System");
      try
      {
        var script = CSharpScript.Create(@"
        using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
        ", option);
        script.RunAsync();

      }
      finally
      {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as you did with System you can do with other assemblies as well, replace line 19 with this and it should work:

```
var option = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences(typeof(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Script).Assembly);
```

Comment: Thanks. So, do I need to add all assemblies I might use in the code? Is there any way to add only assembly files used in the code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to automatically add all the assemblies you're using? Or adding only parts of the assembly you're using? Both of these are not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: Okay, I wanted to add all assemblies to use. So, for instance, if I want to use all codes in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting, do I have to list all assemblies in the libraries?

Comment: Yes, you need to add all the assemblies one by one

Comment: I realized that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` returns all assemblies in a project. So, using this, I can set all assemblies to use. Thanks for your help.